How to change timezone of chart in lightweight_chart_python
Currently when i plot my chart by default 9:30AM is 13:30 i think this is UTC time and not EST.
I'd like to plot the chart in EST how do i do that? Sample code:
from lightweight_charts import PolygonChart

if __name__ == '__main__':
    chart = PolygonChart(
        api_key='<API-KEY>',
        num_bars=200,
        limit=5000,
        live=True
    )
    chart.show(block=True)


I have tried:
        # First localize to UTC, then convert to EST
        est = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
        bar_data['time'].dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert(est)
        chart.set(bar_data, True)

But doesn't seem to do anything. I think my only solution is to actually modify the time and subtract 4 hours. But I'd like to have a proper solution instead of a hacky workaround.
Thanks!

BTW the following hacky workaround works but I would prefer a proper solution.
    # Convert to UTC and then subtract 4 hours
    bar_data['time'] = (bar_data['time']
                   .dt.tz_localize('UTC')
                   .dt.tz_convert('EST')
                   - pd.Timedelta(hours=4))


Found a solution, not optimal but is best solution. It works with daylight savings also:
bar_data['time'] = (bar_data['time'].dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('EST').dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

This converts the date time object into a string without the timezone and this will chart properly through lightweight_charts api.
